# foreach () Error

Tags: php, foreach

I'm getting the following warning when running this script:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

This is the script:

```
$values = array();
foreach ($_POST['rights'] as $right_id)
{
   $values[] = '(' . $id . ', ' . $right_id . ')';
}
```

`$_POST['rights']`/`$id` are integers. In this case it was `$_POST['rights']` = `1,2,3,4,5;` `$id` = `2`.

The strange part is that on a different page with the same kind of input it gives no errors.

**The question:** What is wrong with it?

Comment: Do you mean `$_POST['rights']` is an array of integers? Foreach must take an integer to iterate over.

Comment: Did you confirm that $_POST['rights'] is an array (is it array(1,2,3,4,5) or "1,2,3,4,5"?)

Comment: Check that `$_POST['rights']` is an array first, or typecast it in the `foreach` like `(array) $_POST['rights']`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check `$_POST['rights']`

```
var_dump($_POST['rights']);
```

I think `$_POST['rights']` is not an array.

Comment: After I looked up the second page with the same build up I saw that I indeed forgot to make it an array...

Answer (score 0):

The passed array `$_POST['rights']` probably is empty.

EDIT:

Like Mark Baker said an empty array is fine. You should go with the other answers.

Comment: I echo'd it and it was , at least the last number, 6.

Comment: An empty array would not give an invalid argument warning when used in a foreach.... it's perfectly valid to use an empty array, as long as it's an iterable datatype

Answer (score 0):

`foreach` must take an array, you're passing it an `integer`. You can't iterate over an integer.

A wise move might be to check whatever you're about to iterate over is indeed an array:

```
if(is_array($_POST['rights'])){
    foreach($_POST['rights'] as $value){
        //Whatever you want to do with each $value
    }
}
else {
    //Let the user know it's hit the fan…
    throw new Exception('Help, I\'m not an array :(')
}
```

PHP docs for `array`s: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

PHP docs for `foreach`: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: If you're already checking `$_POST['rights']` is an array, why bother with the typecasting?

Comment: @FDL Thanks for pointing that out. I was going to answer the question differently then I changed my mind. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

As per your statement **$_POST['rights']** is not an array.

It is probably a simple string having 1,2,3,4

You need to convert it into an array with **explode** function.

e.g

```
$_POST['rights'] = explode(",", $_POST['rights']);
```

Then your for loop will work.